# when I used tab bar in bootstrap I can't return to first bar or others bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, navigation, tabbar

I am work in javascript and I used bootstrap component tab bar in  but when I run the code in google chrome first time select the first bar show content if select second bar show content then not worked after that it just show the content of second bar and can't return to first or last bar.

I try to add class "show" but not worked . I used in another div but not worked.

```
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h3 class="heading"> Portofolio </h3>
        <div class="heading-underline"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">first</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">secound</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">last</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="homes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...
        my first show
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <p> my secound show here</p>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="contactss" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab"><p> my last show here </p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fade class from the div. It's an issue with fade class. I faced the same issue and it worked fine after removing fade class.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo error with the ID of the last tab thats why it wasnt showing.

Is this what you want?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h3 class="heading"> Portfolio </h3>
            <div class="heading-underline"></div>
        </div>
    
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">first</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">second</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">last</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...
            my first show</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade " id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                <p> my second show here</p>
    
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade " id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab"><p> my last show here </p></div>
        </div>
        
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: still not worked :( .. if run code is worked but in my site project not worked

Comment: In my project last tab cannot show content and after select second tab cannot return content of first or last tab

Comment: Theres probably an issue with the query. You might have not linked it properly or in  a proper order.

Comment: I use many link of script and uses jquery 3.4.1 and jquery 3.3.1..  is this error happened because that ?!